# Page navigation event

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I was reading trough the documentation for UWP and I got stuck a little.

I have few pages that connect to WCF service taking some information of it few of them download pictures and take few seconds to load.

So I've decided to implement a loading screen while they load however when I try using

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(page));
```

I get stuck in a deadlock state everything freezes while the new page is loading I've tried putting on pageloading event on the other page but this is not helping much since its still locked on the last form.

Does anyone know the right event that I need to call when calling `this.Frame.Navigate()` so I can initialize my loading control while the new frame is loaded?

Comment: Did you try `OnNavigatedTo` event?

Comment: Yes, it does get inside, but doesn't help either and I have also tried Navigate, OnNavigateFrom most of them.

Comment: Does "loading screen" is a page that you will navigate before going to the actual page?

Comment: Did my solution works?

Comment: Your solution is correct for the downloading process but my problem is not the downloading, its the transition between the frames while the new frame is loading. The downloading is handled before the page is even send however the next page that I am calling has a lot of controls in it and the frame is loading a bit slowly before initializing the components that's why I want to have a loading screen while the frame is transitioning itself toward the new frame

Comment: You want to wait until downloaded pictures are loaded. Am I right?

Comment: No I want to display loading while the frame is loading the new frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Navigate to Loading Screen

   ```
   this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(LoadingScreen));
   ```
2. In `OnNavigatedTo` event in LoadingScreen "download pictures"

   ```
   protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   {
       await DownloadPictures();
       //After downloading, navigate to the next page
       this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(page)); 
   }
   ```

Comment: Your answer was correct although I had to put it on page loaded and hide the controls since the progress control was not initialized while navigating

Answer (score 0):

try launching the view on a separate window like this

```
       try
        {
            CoreApplicationView Nv= CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
            var z = CoreApplication.MainView;

            int id= 0;
            await 
    Nv.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                Frame frame = new Frame();
                frame.Navigate(typeof(page));

                Window.Current.Content = frame;
                // You have to activate the window in order to show it later.
                Window.Current.Activate();




                id= ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
            });
            bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(id);


        }
        catch (Exception eee)
        {
            Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog errorBox =
               new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Couldn't Create New 
          Window: " + eee.Message);
            await errorBox.ShowAsync();


        }
```

Comment: My current functionality already implement this method however I want to find a way to do it from the current frame not open a new window.

Comment: @KristiforMilchev your question post is too abstract and doesnt provide enough info for anyone to play around.

Comment: There is nothing abstract, I need an event that would file asynchronously while the transition between the two frame is made, something like your answer but avoiding opening a new Frame.